# I restore my job from a 1.8GB savepoint, then inmediately create a new savepoint and this one is ~50MB in size. Where did my state go?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I'm using the command:

`flink run jarfile.jar -s savepoint`

Notice I'm  not using the -n option, so I don't expect any data loss in that regard. Moreover, I'm following the guidelines given by the [savepoint guide](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/ops/state/savepoints.html), that is, assigning UIDs to each operator.

I'm using Flink version 1.9.1.

Comment: Did you enable incremental snapshots?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov yes, I'm using RocksDB and have incremental snapshots enabled. However, my understanding is that this only affects checkpointing. Savepoints and checkpoints are independent, right?

Comment: Are you using processing or event time?

Comment: Oh, your were taking another *savepoint* after loading all the data? Hmmm, are there any windows accumulating state that may have been released after reload?

Comment: @ArvidHeise I'm using event time.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov My app is fairly complex and I do use windows, but the bulk of the state is in two operators that store objects permanently.

Comment: You could use the state processor API to examine both savepoints. I've got an example of how to dump out keyed state in https://github.com/ververica/flink-training-exercises/blob/master/src/main/java/com/ververica/flinktraining/solutions/datastream_java/state_processor/ReadRidesAndFaresSnapshot.java

Comment: @DavidAnderson thanks, I will look into this. I was thinking about using the queryable state API but I was afraid of messing with the job. With this it seems I can circumvent that problem.

Comment: I'm very interested in helping you, but with the current information, I'm lost. If you use state processor API and figure out the diff, please update the question.